# Copiar índices de un array en otro array en C

Tags: array, c, indices

Necesito copiar los índices de un array en otro en C, lo más eficiente posible.

Por ejemplo si tengo el array:

```
datos = [4,8,10,12,15]
```

El array 2 debería darme lo siguiente:

```
indices = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

O sea, de alguna manera (en el ejemplo) el valor "4" debería estar asociado al índice "0", el "8" al índice "1" y así...

Siempre los datos van a estar ordenados de menor a mayor.

El objetivo sería hacerlo lo más eficiente posible, **no quiero usar un for, que me va a dar de orden n (O(n)).**

Lo que intenté hacer es un memcpy, pero lo único que logré fue copiar el mismo arreglo (los datos solamente).

Gracias!!

Comment: No acabo de entender a qué te refieres con índices. ¿Te refieres a que `4` es el primero (índice `0`), `8` es el segundo (índice `1`), etc... ?

Comment: Si @PaperBirdMaster, esos serían los índices. En el índice `0` está el `4`, en el índice `1` el `8`, en el índice `3` el `10` y asi...

Comment: Pero ¿los índices son esos porque el array original está ordenado o aunque el array original estuviese desordenado los índices serían los mismos?

Comment: Los índices son esos porque el array está ordenado, sino serían otros. Si pongo otro ejemplo: `datos = [20, 55, 9, 2] ` los índices serían que el `0` está con el `20`, el `1` con el `55` y asi.. Pero en mi caso, siempre va a estar ordenado el arreglo

Comment: No veo que los índices cambien con el array desordenado, entendería que los índices de `[20,55,9,2]` fuesen `[2,3,1,0]` no `[0,1,2,3]`.

Comment: Ah claro claro.. Entendi mal la pregunta anterior. Es así como decis vos. Porque yo despues voy a modificar el array y me va a quedar desordenado y queda como decís vos. Si el de datos es `[20, 55, 9, 2]` el de índices quedaría `[2, 3, 1, 0]`. Perdón había entendido mal

Comment: Aclarado. ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Pense que el memcpy hacía eso pero claramente no, solo me copiaba los datos. Nada que ver con los índices. Pero no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo. No se si será muy dificil o no.

Comment: `memcpy` copia lo que hay. Primero tienes que calcular los índices ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: conoces el tamaño de tu array original "datos"?

Comment: Si. Lo conozco siempre

Comment: Con un for sería muy sencillo... vas añadiendo valores a indices desde 0 hasta el tamaño de tu array datos.

Comment: Si, esa opción la pense pero sería muy costosa. Tengo arrays de 2 millones o más a veces, y tardaría muchísimo. No se si habrá otra forma

Comment: Creo que no hay otra forma, pero si intentas hacerlo óptimo, podrías plantearte meter OPENMP para ese for ya que sería muy fácil de paralelizar

Comment: Ah eso no se me había ocurrido, ahí averiguo entonces más sobre eso. Gracias!

Comment: te pongo una respuesta ahora con un ejemplo del código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo de un **for** para hacer lo que pides pero paralelizado con OpenMP.

```
int count = datos.length; //aquí iría el tamaño de tu array datos
int indices[100];
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) //i es privada por defecto al crearse dentro del for
{
    indices[i]=i;
}
```

> Para que funcione debes incluir la librería **omp.h** y compilar con la bandera -fopenmp

Ejemplo de compilación:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -fopenmp
```

Comment: Buenísimo, gracias